# React Hooks Scroll to Element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking to write a React hook with React 16.8.6 that will let me scroll to a particular HTML element section on click of a navigation item. I have a `Navigation` component that is a sibling of the sections rendered on the page.

Also when the page scrolls, I would like to update state of the `App` with that HTML section.

### Navigation Component JSX

```
<ul class="nav>
   <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
   <li><a>Section 2</a></li>          
</ul>
```

### Sections in Home Page at App Level Component

```
<section className="section-1">Section 1</section>
<section className="section-2">Section 2</section>
```

### Hooks

```
const [navItem, setNavItem] = React.useState(null);
const sectionRef = React.useRef(null);

// Scroll To Item
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sectionRef.current);
    if (sectionRef.current) {
      sectionRef.current.scrollToItem();
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: Is your navigation and sections kept in the same component file?

Comment: Updated description... The <Nav/> component is separate from those sections, but they render on that single page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't mind using `react-router-dom`, then you can track history changes and update the scroll position to an HTML element's `id` via a `hash` history change. The advantage of this approach is you don't have to utilize state, nor utilize refs, and it can scale across the entire application (regardless of where the elements are located within the application's tree, you can scroll to them).

**Working example**:

https://fglet.codesandbox.io/ (demo)

https://codesandbox.io/s/fglet (source -- unfortunately, doesn't work within the codesandbox editor)

---

**components/ScrollHandler** (hook that listens to hash history changes, searches for elements that match the id located within the hash and, if it finds a matching element id, then it'll scroll to the element)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const ScrollHandler = ({ location }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById(location.hash));

    setTimeout(() => {
      window.scrollTo({
        behavior: element ? "smooth" : "auto",
        top: element ? element.offsetTop : 0
      });
    }, 100);
  }, [location]);

  return null;
};

ScrollHandler.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: PropTypes.string,
    search: PropTypes.string,
    hash: PropTypes.string,
    state: PropTypes.any,
    key: PropTypes.string
  }).isRequired
};

export default withRouter(ScrollHandler);
```

**components/Navigation** (links to change url hash history location)

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import List from "../List";

const Navigation = () => (
  <List>
    {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(num => (
      <li key={num}>
        <Link to={`/#section${num}`}>Section {num}</Link>
      </li>
    ))}
  </List>
);

export default Navigation;
```

**components/Sections** (the `Headline` component contains the `id` that will be matched against)

```
import React from "react";
import Headline from "../Headline";

const Sections = () =>
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(num => (
    <Headline key={num} id={`#section${num}`}>
      Section {num}
    </Headline>
  ));

export default Sections;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Container from "./components/Container";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import Sections from "./components/Sections";
import ScrollHandler from "./components/ScrollHandler";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Container>
      <ScrollHandler />
      <Navigation />
      <Sections />
    </Container>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using React Router V6. Some things didn't work and were different. For instance, `withRouter` was deprecated. React router offered a solution if you need it ([link](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it)).

My solution for V6:

Create a component `WithRouter.jsx`:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

Create a component `ScrollHandler.jsx`

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import WithRouter from "./WithRouter";

const ScrollHandler = ({ location }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById(location.hash.substring(1));

    if (element) element.scrollIntoView();
  }, [location]);

  return null;
};

export default WithRouter(ScrollHandler);
```

In `index.js` I wrapped my `<App/>` comp with the `BrowserRouter as Router` like so:

```
<Router>
   <App />
</Router>
```

Then in `App.js`, add the `<ScrollHandler/>` component:

```
<ScrollHandler location={location} />
```