# react I want to know how to jump to text within a single page

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and I want to create a index at the top of the page to jump to text.  So I have a bunch of very long text pages with sections.  I want the top to have

section 1
section 2
section 3

and when you click one you jump down in the page to that section.

I tried to use link to with an id in the

. but does not do anything.

any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Try using anchors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280369/use-anchors-with-react-router

Comment: You can find also this solution [React Hooks Scroll to Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420392/react-hooks-scroll-to-element/56421201) that can provide an experience where you click and scroll to an specific element.